# Why a question can exist with no tags?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tagging, suggested-edits

Why a question can exist with **no tags**?

For example https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/613902/revisions.

Comment: Looks like this is a bug with suggested edits, there's another instance of this on a different site: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/147067/revisions

Comment: I concur, this is a bug.

Comment: Although I don't think it happened in this case, something similar can happen when a question is migrated to M.SE and none of the tags exist as tags here, although I think it actually gives the question the tag (no-tags).

Comment: @Daniel I thought it was [tag:untagged].

Comment: @ColeJohnson That's likely. I just recalled from (a rather poor) memory.

Comment: Either way, this is a duplicate of a MSO post.

Comment: @Cole Johnson: Thanks for telling us that untagged question will fall into the [tag:untagged] "tag".

Comment: @ColeJohnson, can you link to the MSO post, perhaps by editing it into the top of the question?

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for the report.

We did a major tag change on Dec. 20<sup>th</sup>, this introduced this bug and was fixed an hour later on the same day.